# Добавить значение в textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку в textbox добавлялась следущая по алфавиту буква.

```
var alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  a_t=alph.split("");
  for(i=0;i<p;i++){
    str="main_form.t_"+n+".value+=a_t[i]";
    eval(str);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример решения задачи используя генераторы:

```js
const alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const button = document.querySelector('button');


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 let result =  generator.next();
  textarea.textContent +=  result.value||'';
})

const generator = addChar(alph);

function* addChar(str) {
  for (let i = 0; i <str.length; i++) {
    yield str[i];
  }
  return '';
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button>click me </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

+- так можно сделать

```js
const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
const textInput = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]')
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click',
  e => {
    let currentValue = textInput.value
    if (currentValue.length >= letters.length) return

    textInput.value = currentValue + letters[currentValue.length]
  })
```

```html
<input style="width:100%" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="+" />
```